# How change Android Studio project api version to 23

Tags: android-studio, api-versioning

I use Android Studio3.2.
I create a project use api version 28.
Now I need change api version to 23.
So I edit build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}
```

And I change "AppCompatActivity" to "Activity"

But building faild:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
.............................
```

Comment: Hi @Getname, for this you should add the material support like compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.x.x'

Comment: I think you also need to downgrade your dependencies in gradle like constraintlayout, etc.

Comment: thank you @Varma but how add the material support?

Comment: thank you @Yasir but how to downgrade dependencies? I try change implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2' to implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0' this not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to look inside you XML for a view that has style type mentioned in that error.

Also, try to go File/ InvalidateCaches

Comment: Marovic, hey you can mention this in comment also. sorry to say, this is not a solution at all and read the stackoverflow rules. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** should match and apart from that

you have to include the following support library to support api 23

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

then now sync project and check.

Hope this will help